# My search function for my array (subarrays) seems to be malfunctioning

Tags: python, json

Ok, so I have a database program. Every I have implemented works right now except my search function, it seems to print out all the sub arrays instead of the one searched. I havn't been able to pinpoint the problem so I was hoping if you guys could help me in some way with a solution. Thanks to all that help!

My code:

```
import json
import time

datastore = json.load(open("file.json"))
menuon = 1


def add_user():
    userdata = input("How many users do you wish to input?")
    print("\n")

    if (userdata == 0):
        print("Thank you, have a nice day!")

    else:
        loop = int(userdata)
        whileloop = loop+loop

        while loop < whileloop:
            appendnumber = json.load(open("fileappend.json"))
            loop = loop + 1
            datastore.append([])
            datastore[appendnumber].append(input("Enter Name: "))
            datastore[appendnumber].append(input("Enter Email: "))
            datastore[appendnumber].append(input("Enter DOB: "))
            appendnumber = appendnumber + 1
            json.dump(appendnumber, open("fileappend.json", "w"))


def print_resource(array):
    for entry in datastore:
        print("Name:  "+entry[0])
        print("Email:  "+entry[1])
        print("DOB:  "+entry[2])
        print("\n")


def search_function(value):
  for eachperson in datastore:
      if value in eachperson:
          print_resource(eachperson)


while menuon == 1:        
    print("Hello There. What would you like to do?")
    print("")
    print("Option 1: Add Users")
    print("Option 2: Search Users")
    print("Option 3: Replace Users")
    print("Option 4: End the program")
    menuChoice = input()

    if menuChoice == '1':
        add_user()

    if menuChoice == '2':
        searchflag = input("Do you wish to search the user data? y/n")
        if(searchflag == 'y'):
            criteria = input("Enter Search Term: ")
            search_function(criteria)

    if menuChoice == '3':
        break

    if menuChoice == '4':
        print("Ending in 3...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("2")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("1")
        json.dump(datastore, open("file.json", "w"))
        menuon=0
```

file.json contains:

```
"[["Brandon Jones", "FluxDZ@hotmail.co.uk", "01/07/1999"],]"
```

fileappend.json contains:
1

Comment: What's supposed to be in `file.json` and `fileappend.json` before you run it? (Obviously not nothing, or you'd get a `FileNotFoundError` or a `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.)

Comment: @abarnert These files already exist on my pc so the program was ready to run, file.json is the arrays save file where the fileappend.json keeps track of the position in the array to apply the new accounts to.

Comment: Then give us some starting files we can use. If you want people to debug your code, you need to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that they can run.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry about that, including a little part at the bottom of the OP to explain whats currently in the files :)

Comment: With those values, you get a `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` at startup. Are you sure there are quotes around what's in `file.json` like that? Because without the quotes it looks like it would work.

Comment: Actually, even without the extra quotes, you get an error because of the stray comma. But if I put just `[["Brandon Jones", "FluxDZ@hotmail.co.uk", "01/07/1999"]]` in the file, it works fine. And I can't see your problem. If I search for `Brandon Jones` or `FluxDZ@hotmail.co.uk` it prints out the record; if I search for `Joan Brand` it prints out nothing.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory as the Python code. And the error makes perfect sense; that isn't a valid JSON string, so it's not surprising that `json.load` fails to interpret it.

Comment: Delete the two places the json's load, then run the program once and reinsert the load parts of the code for it to work. Best I can help. Just make sure to replace the first load method with " datastore = []"

Comment: Add a second user and search, it outputs both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't your search function, but your print function:

```
def print_resource(array):
    for entry in datastore:
        print("Name:  "+entry[0])
        print("Email:  "+entry[1])
        print("DOB:  "+entry[2])
        print("\n")
```

You pass it a parameter, `array`, but it completely ignores that parameter and instead loops over each entry in the whole datastore, printing them all.

Try this:

```
def print_resource(entry):
    print("Name:  "+entry[0])
    print("Email:  "+entry[1])
    print("DOB:  "+entry[2])
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you, Worked like a charm and understood the explanation!

Comment: BTW, pylint or similar tools would've flagged an unused variable automatically.

Comment: @dstromberg: +1. Many people think of `pylint` as a "polishing" tool after they've got their code working, and don't realize how useful it can be as a debugging tool as well.